# Problems with pipenv

Tags: python, pipenv, python-3.9

I'm trying to create a virtual environment. For this, I install pipenv from the terminal:

```
>pip install pipenv
```

No problem.

And then, when trying to install a package, or do about anything from pipenv, I can't do it.

```
>pipenv install requests
```

Error:

```
pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pipenv install requests
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Please, help me! I've tried with older versions of the pipenv package and I can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: use `python -m pipenv install requests`

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat my ultimate goal is to create a virtual environment. And my actual problem is that I can't make pipenv to work.

Comment: @sahasrara62 THANK YOU!!!! May I ask what's going on? Why can't I just run the way I was trying to. I saw it was being done that way in a course.

Comment: this is because in course (video tutorial i assume) they consider that only one python version  is installed in system and it is configured, so when ever you call python, pip in terminal or command prompt, it invoke that python env there, but sometime what what in your system there are more than one pthon env install and configured which can be invoked by keywork like python, python3.7 or python3.8. so when you install pip in system it get associated with system level configured default python and when you try to install package with pip then they install for that default python only not other

Comment: so to avoid this confusion, to with which python env you should install package, (in my opinion) it is better to use that python invocation and  package invocation by adding `-m` with it (representing modul) ie `python -m pip install  <package>` so this will install the packge with that python env only not with other, i strongly suggest you to go through some book along with video course for more understanding

Comment: @sahasrara62: would you please consider changing your comments into proper answer?

Comment: @sophros done, added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `python -m pip install requests`

This is happening because of the different version of python stored in your system,
and pip associated with that version is different.

for example: in your system default python can be 2.7 and the python 3 versions can be 3.6. which invoke by running `python` and `python3` respectively in terminal.

Now if you use `pip` (`pip install requests`) then it will install the requests in python2.7 ie the default one with which pip is associated.

not to install with python3.6 you need to call pip associated with it by `pip3 install requests`.

so this will create confusion. So it is good practice if you call the pip by using python invoke-command ie `python -m pip install <package name>`

so this will install the package in the python environment where you are working or want to work.